# PowerShell not working in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: unity, 19.10, powershell

I use Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

PowerShell Version: latest/stable 6.2.3, source: snap store;

PowerShell starting fail log:

```
FailFast:
Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.

   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.StringComparer..cctor()
   at System.AppDomain.InitializeCompatibilityFlags()
   at System.AppDomain.Setup(System.Object)
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command :

```
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
```

Then run `pwsh` or `pwsh-preview` depends on what version th

Comment: Tried with pwsh works pwsh-preview did not work.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1184143/edit) your answer please? it's seems that you didn't finish to write it